# How to code Javascript behavior for success messages

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to fix behavior of a small form in javascript. The user fills out the calculator and clicks the button. Then the next from will popup. When the user clicks send message I want to see a success message and I cant get that to happen. Also there is a capcha I cant get the error message to work as well.

```html
<!-- Calculator -->
<div class="col-md-8" style="padding-top: 20px;">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="/action_page.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label " for="pads">Qty of Pad Sets used Per Month:</label>
            <div>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="pads" value="200" placeholder="Amount" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="costs">Cost per Pad Set:</label>
            <div>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cost" value="35" placeholder="$" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label " for="life">
                Current Pad Shelf Life
                <br />
                (in months):
            </label>
            <div>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="life" value="24" placeholder="months" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <a class="">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" id="calc" onclick="openForm()" href="#">Submit</a>
        </div>
        <!-- To show savings, to be removed -->
        <div id="calc-result" class="result"></div>
        <div id="calc-result1" class="result1"></div>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- End Calculator -->
</div>

<!-- Pop up -->
<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlContact" runat="server" Visible="true">
        <h1>How can we reach you?</h1>
        <p>Please fill out the information below and we will send your savings directly to your email! </p>

        <form name="sentMessage" runat="server"
            id="contactForm" novalidate>
            <div class="control-group form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <label>First Name:</label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="firstName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="control-group form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <label>Last Name:</label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="lastName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="control-group form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <label>Company:</label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="company" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="control-group form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <label>Defib Brand:</label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="brand" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="control-group form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <label>Email Address:</label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="emailAddress" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address."></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="control-group form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <label>Message:</label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="message" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="150px" MaxLength="999" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message."></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=""></div>
            &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblCaptchaError" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="Please check captcha and try again." /><br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnSendMessage" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Send Message" />
        </form>
    </asp:Panel>

    <div id="divsuccess" runat="server" visible="false">
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblSuccess" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Red" Visible="true">Thank you for your message, someone will respond to your request as soon as possible.</asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
 function openForm() {
            document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
            document.querySelector('.form-horizontal').style.display = 'none';
        }
        function closeForm() {
            document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
        }

        function sendMessage() {
            // code to send message

            // display success message
            document.getElementById("lblSuccess").style.display = "block";
        }
```

Comment: You appear to be mixing PHP and ASP.NET WebForms together as your `<form>` has `action="/action_page.php"` but your markup is WebForms `.aspx` (`<asp:TextBox runat="server">` so I have 2 questions: **why and how** did this happen, and secondly: _why_ are you still using WebForms in 2023?

Comment: Anyway, your `document.getElementById("lblSuccess")` calls will fail because (by default) ASP.NET WebForms re-writes rendered `id=""` attributes to include all ancestor control's IDs, s. your `lblSuccess` `id=""` will likely be `ctl001_foobar_ctl003_lblSuccess` or something equally hideous. You can override this on each control, but I think a better option is to just **stop using WebForms**: it isn't supported at all in ASP.NET Core (since 2016) and WebForms was _effectively_ obsoleted back in 2008 when ASP.NET MVC came out.